# moving between directories in python

Tags: python, directory, path, operating-system

I have a simple filebrowser class that has buttons at the top with the path directory names on them. Currently it starts in the file directory.  What I am trying to do is, when a button is clicked, it should switch to that directory.  Everything else is working, the files are listed for the current dir and the buttons show and I can click on them. The code in the browser is like this:

```
    self.base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    self.dir = directory
    self.load_images()
    
    self.path = os.path.abspath(self.base_dir)
    self.path_list = self.path.split(os.path.sep)
    self.path_button_panel = Buttonbar(self.rect.width, 25, HORIZONTAL)
    
    for dir_path in self.path_list:
        b = Button(dir_path, action = self.set_directory)
        self.path_button_panel.add(b)
```

and the buttons are like this:

home marienbad python3 pygame filetest

so when I click python3 it should change to that.  The buttons work, they just have the directory name as their text and return that to the set_directory method.

So in set_directory I tried:

```
new_path = os.path.abspath(directory)
```

but this made a path which just appended it to the current dir path.

I tried splitting the path and rejoining:

```
    new_path = os.path.split(directory)
    new_path = os.path.join(new_path, directory)
```

but it said it wanted a path like object.

I have tried several things and it is just frustrating me now! I am seriously confused, I thought there would be some way to split the path to the directory name but can't suss it out.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.split` returns a tuple `(head, tail)`, so in your case `new_path` is a tuple. Use `os.path.dirname` instead: this returns the next directory 'up' from the path supplied e.g. `os.path.dirname('/path/to/my/thing')` returns `'/path/to/my'` which I think is what you wanted.

`os.path.abspath` resolves a relative path into an absolute one e.g. changes `'./data'` into `'C:/User/MyAccount/Documents/work/myPackage/data'` if you are currently in the folder `'C:/User/MyAccount/Documents/work/myPackage'`.

Comment: Thanks. That works when it is the directory before, but in my example, if I wanted to go to the python3 directory it doesn't work.

Comment: So do you just need to get rid of the `os.path.split` line then? I presumed `directory` held the current directory. So you just want to append the folder name to it i.e. `os.path.join(directory, folder_name)`?

Comment: I fixed it by sending each button the full path but only setting the name to the last item in the path.